# Расширение Google Maps для Yii

Tags: google-maps-api, php, yii

Требуется взять базу данных и отметить на карте адреса, как на примере ниже:

`http://demo.symphonythemes.com/drupal7/bizreview/`

Сделать это все надо на Yii.
Может, кто-то знает подходящее расширение для реализации такой задачи?

Заранее благодарен за комментарии или какие-нибудь рекомендации...

Comment: Сделайте виджет сами. В моем опыте уже готовое решение редко подходило под мои задачи. Очень часто приходится допиливать...

Answer (score 4):

Я бы Вам порекомендовал все-таки использовать напрямую JS API без расширений всяких. Вам достаточно [создать карту](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru#Map) и [добавить маркеры](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru#Marker).

[Пример](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=ru)